# Constructor issues passing a parameter with an Aggregation relationship

Tags: java

I have two classes with an aggregation relationship. When I instantiate an object from main, it doesn't initialize in one of the classes. However, if I manually type in the values that I try to pass in main, it compiles. Here are the fields and the constructors. If you think I need to post the rest of the code, I will. I don't know if I'm just blind or not. FYI, I'm a beginner, so I apologize ahead of time if my terminology is bad.

Main:

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Patient person = new Patient("Please", "Helpme", "01/01/2016", "Broncos", "Insurance of Broncos");
      Treatment treatment1 = new Treatment("08/4/2015", "1:00", "1:20", person3);
   }
}
```

Class Treatment: This is where the issue is. It's "person = new Patient(aPerson);".

```
public class Treatment
{
   private Date treatmentDate;
   private Time startTime;
   private Time endTime;
   private Patient person; 

   public Treatment(String aDate, String sTime, String eTime, Patient aPerson)
   {
      treatmentDate = new Date(aDate);
      startTime = new Time(sTime);
      endTime = new Time(eTime); 
      person = new Patient(aPerson);
   }
```

Class Patient:

```
public class Patient extends Person
{
   final private int NUM = 10;
   private String employer;
   private String InsuranceCompany;
   private int treatmentCount = 0;
   private String[] a1 = new String[NUM];
   public Patient(String aFName, String aLName, String aDate, String anEmployer, String anInsurranceCompany)
   {
      super(aFName, aLName, aDate);
      String firstName = aFName;
      employer = anEmployer;
      InsuranceCompany = anInsurranceCompany;  
   }
```

Here is the error message I'm getting:

----jGRASP exec: javac -g Treatment.java
Treatment.java:20: error: constructor Patient in class Patient cannot be applied to given types;
      person = new Patient(aPerson);
               ^
  required: String,String,String,String,String
  found: Patient
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

Now if I go to the Treatment class and manually input those values from main versus a parameter, it will compile. Any suggestions and guidance would greatly be appreciated. As stated before, if posting the rest of the code for the classes will help, I'll gladly do so.

Comment: Shouldn't  Treatment treatment1 = new Treatment("08/4/2015", "1:00", "1:20", person3); have person object? Where is person3 created?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you forgot to define the constructor as Patient(Patient p)? Try to add this to your Patient class:

```
public Patient(Patient p) {
  this(p.fName, p.lName, p.date, p.employer, p.InsuranceCompany);
}
```

Also you need to either make the first 3 values from Person protected or use a getter method instead

```
public class Patient extends Person {

final private int NUM = 10;
private String employer;
private String InsuranceCompany;
private final int treatmentCount = 0;
private final String[] a1 = new String[NUM];

public Patient(String aFName, String aLName, String aDate) {
    super(aFName, aLName, aDate);
}

public Patient(String aFName, String aLName, String aDate, String anEmployer, String anInsurranceCompany) {
    super(aFName, aLName, aDate);
    String firstName = aFName;
    employer = anEmployer;
    InsuranceCompany = anInsurranceCompany;
}

public Patient(Patient p) {
    this(p.fName, p.lName, p.date, p.employer, p.InsuranceCompany);
}
}
```

And class Person:

```
public class Person {

protected String fName;
protected String lName;
protected String date;

public Person(String aFName, String aLName, String aDate) {
    fName = aFName;
    lName = aLName;
    date = aDate;
}
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. This is my constructor in Patient.

Comment: public Patient(String aFName, String aLName, String aDate, String anEmployer, String anInsurranceCompany)
   {

Comment: But in `person = new Patient(aPerson);` you are not passing the parameters, you are passing an object instead.  You need to implement this constructor.

Comment: The compiler knows how to construct a Patient object form 5 Strings.  But it does not know how to construct a Patient object from another Patient object.  You need to implement a constructor with one parameter as an Patient object to teach the compiler.  And that what the code I wrote for you suppose to do.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I don't know if this helps either but class Patient is a subclass of Person. When I put in your code, this is what I get.                                 Patient.java:19: error: constructor Person in class Person cannot be applied to given types;
   {
   ^
  required: String,String,String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
Patient.java:20: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
      return this(p.fName, p.lName, p.date, p.employer, p.InsuranceCompany);
                 ^
2 errors

Comment: Sorry, remove the return before this(

Answer (score 0):

You are making a call to a constructor which does not exist from  :

```
person = new Patient(aPerson); // this is a call to Patient(String arg) constructor


Patient(Patient patient) {
     // do something here
}
```

Or the other way use it with current code as

```
person = new Patient(String aFName, String aLName, String aDate, String anEmployer, 
             String anInsurranceCompany); // where you need to initialise(define) all these args as well.
```

That's what the compiler says too -

> required: `String,String,String,String,String` *but* found: `Patient` reason:
>   **actual and formal argument lists differ in length** 1 error

Comment: I see what you guys are saying and doing now, thank you.

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet, but I know what the issue is. Now I'm trying to figure out how to get the contents of the the parameter of the p from the public Patient(Patient p) constructor. This is irritating.